# Embedding Flash & Quicktime Via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, quicktime

I have a JavaScript function that loads a flash movie into a webpage div using swfobject.embedSWF().

I want to be able to, alternatively, load a .mov file into the same div, in the event that this is the file found instead of the .swf.

Is there a close equivalent to swfobject.embedSWF for the purposes of embedding a .mov file?  If not, what is an efficient route to doing this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QTObject`](http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/01/26/web-standards-compliant-javascript-quicktime-detect-and-embed/) might do what you need and it's from the same author as `SWFObject`.  It's old though, so I'm not sure if it will work well in modern browsers.

**EDIT** I searched and found reports of it working fine in IE7, Firefox 2 and Opera 9, so you might just be in luck.  Just make sure you test it thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you, that looks functional!  There's the slight headache of it not taking a parameter for which page element to write the QT movie into... but life wouldn't be fun without a few challenges...

Comment: Oh wait, no, myQTObject.write("display_area") does work.  So it's basically perfect!  Many thanks.